# Python Round 3 decimals places with Decimal() and perform a rounding twice or more

Tags: python, decimal

I need to round my input twice when they have 3 decimal places and to do that, I round the input twice as follow:

```
3.445 -> 3.45 -> 3.5
```

Is there a better way to achieve this or my code below is fine?

```
number = 3.445
print Decimal(number).quantize(Decimal("0.001"),                          
        decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).quantize(Decimal("0.01"),
            decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).quantize(Decimal("0.1"),
                decimal.ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

Comment: Why do you want to round twice? Why do you want 3.5 instead of 3.4, which is closer?

Comment: And why are you rounding *three* times?

Comment: Because the last 5 turn the 4 to its left to a 5 and so forth... This is what my client asked me. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Soichiro. I would love to get some insight into *why* your client wants to do it like that. Is there a good reason or are they just being dense?

Comment: Also, how do they plan on handling negative numbers?

Comment: @user2357112 I round 3 times because I want the input with one decimal place in this case.

Comment: @MadPhysicist If there is a negative number in the input, that input gets deleted by the user.

Comment: @MadPhysicist To be honest, I did not ask why he wants it this way :(

Comment: @Soichiro. Be careful with that.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What do you mean?

Comment: I mean the rabbit hole of poorly understood requirements.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Actually today, I talked to him about this and after a little chat, he agreed to change it.

Comment: So perhaps you would consider deleting this question? I doubt it would be useful to anyone in the future, given how made up the rounding methodology is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, all you want to do is round *up* to one decimal place. In that case, this should do the job:

```
myDecimal = Decimal(3.445)
myDecimal.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -1, rounding=decimal.ROUND_UP)
```